# How to subscribe AWS SNS Topic in React Native (Android)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, react-native

I tried with the aws-sdk-react-native module:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-react-native

The configuration took some time, but thanks to this links I could i.e. list the topics:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-react-native/issues/35

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-react-native/blob/master/SNS/IntegrationTests/SNSTests.js

The test includes a sample how to subscribe to get emails but not how to get notifications in the app. I don't know how to get the platformEndpoint, the PlatformApplicationArn and the deviceToken.

```
endPoint = sns.createPlatformEndpoint({
  PlatformApplicationArn: '{APPLICATION_ARN}',
  Token: '{DEVICE_TOKEN}'
})
...
var subscribeRequest= {
  "Protocol":"application",
  "TopicArn":topicARN,
  "Endpoint":endPoint
}
try{
  await AWSSNS.Subscribe(subscribeRequest);
}catch(e){
  console.error(e);
  shouldResolve = false;
  return shouldResolve;
}
```

Are there any samples for this? 
I'm also looking for an authentication sample.
Would it be easier to use firebase?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I have used `GCM` over SNS to send notifications. Here are the steps I went through assuming you already set up `GCM` and added required libraries from `AWS React Native SDK`:

First create a `SNS` app from AWS:

[image]

Then you need to create Federated Identity through `Cognito` service of AWS. This is required for sending your device token from mobile app to AWS SNS app. Choose `Manage Federated Identities`

[image]

Then create your pool, don't forget to check `Enable Access to unauthenticated identities`
[image]

When you create the pool you will need to create IAM Roles for `unauthenticated` and `authenticated` roles of that pool. AWS will help you create new roles for that but you need to go to `IAM Roles` menu and attach `AmazonSNSFullAccess` to created roles, otherwise from the mobile app you won't able to send device token.

[image]

After doing these steps you will able send your device token using Amazon's React Native SDK. I have written a helper class for sending token to AWS SNS as suggested here:

```
class AWSUtility {

  constructor() {
    const region = "us-west-1"; //change it with your region
    const IDENTITY_POOL_ID = "pool id created from Federated Identities"
    AWSCognitoCredentials.initWithOptions({region, identity_pool_id: IDENTITY_POOL_ID});
    AWSSNS.initWithOptions({region});
  }

  addTokenToAWSSNS(token, snsEndpointARN) {
    const applicationArn = "change with SNS application Amazon resource name";
    return Promise.try(() => {
      if (!snsEndpointARN) {
        return this.createPlatformEndpoint(token, applicationArn);
      } else {
        return AWSSNS.GetEndpointAttributes({EndpointArn: snsEndpointARN})
          .then((result) => {
            const {Attributes = {}} = result;
            const {Token, Enabled} = Attributes;
            const updateNeeded = Token !== token || Enabled !== 'true';
            if (updateNeeded) {
              return this.updateEndpoint(token).then(() => result.EndpointArn);
            }
            return snsEndpointARN;
          })
          .catch(() => {
            this.createPlatformEndpoint(token, applicationArn)
          });
      }
    });
  }

  updateEndpoint(snsEndpointARN, token) {
    //AWS is returning error saying that it requires 6 params to update endpoint, if anyone has any idea about it let me know please
    return AWSSNS.SetEndpointAttributes({EndpointArn: snsEndpointARN, Attributes: {Token: token, Enabled: true}});
  }

  createPlatformEndpoint(token, applicationArn) {
    return AWSSNS.CreatePlatformEndpoint({Token: token, PlatformApplicationArn: applicationArn})
      .then(result => result.EndpointArn)
      .catch((error = {}) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}

export default new AWSUtility();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it helped me understand the logic behind disabled endpoints. During my own implementation I noticed you may be missing some promise() calls to get the promise from the AWSSNS functions. Am I correct or is that handled somewhere else on your side?

Comment: Its been quite a long time, so don't remember it very well :)

Comment: oh ok, no worries, I got everything working now. I also noticed you have to pass in everything as a string to setEndpointAttributes, so that would become Enabled: "true"